# How to make this saturated text effect?

Tags: text, adobe-after-effects

[image: found this on YouTube. Wondered how to do it]

This is a popular effect on YouTube. Anyone know how to do it

Comment: How is the text more saturated? It's just lighter. At the very least, it's _less_ saturated than the background. Also, would it be too much to ask to show some effort, like what you've tried and what didn't work? Or at least a question mark behind your question?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if it works like Photoshop but it should, anyway, you have to "play" with the text layer blending mode until you find the right one to produce that kind of effect. You could try "Overlay" or "Vivid Light" which should give you that result.

You can also visit the Adobe support page if you want more information about blending modes in After Effects. Heres the link:

https://helpx.adobe.com/after-effects/using/blending-modes-layer-styles.html

Comment: This answer has the essential. It works like in PS.  Except there are more available blending modes in AE. You can have for example grey text with blending mode Linear Dodge (=Add) . The lighter text, the more white is the result. Maybe you noticed that the 1 is partially erased or masked off.

Answer (score 0):

- First add the text you want
- Then add an adjustment layer between the text and your footage
- Apply the contrast and brightness effect to the adjustement layer and turn the brightness down
- Then on the adjustment layer adjust the alpha matte drop down box so that the whole clip is dark apart from where the text is